# Computing complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the contour integral $$ \int_\gamma\frac{z}{2z+1} \mathrm{d}z $$ over a counterclockwise unit square in $\mathbb {C}$ i.e $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $\leq y \leq 1$.

By Cauchy's inegral theorem this integral vanishes,because taken any open simply connected subset $U$ of $\mathbb{ C}$ which contains the unit square and $\frac{-1}{2} \notin U$ the function $f=\frac{z}{2z+1}$ is analytic on $U$ . Is there any flaw in my argument?

Comment: What is the domain of $y$? Also over $[0,1]$?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @khil Seems like your logit is correct. The only pole is not in the area of interest, so it should be $0$.